# Building HTML in Servlet adding extra quotes

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp

So I am trying to build some HTML markup in a Spring controller. Sample code:

```
append(sb ,"<div class=&quot;myDiv&quot;>");
```

which is generating the following HTML source on browser:

```
<div class=""myDiv"">
```

**append code:**

```
private void append(StringBuilder sb, String value) {
         sb.append(value).append(System.getProperty("line.separator")).append('\n');
}
```

My question is, Why generated HTML code has an extra set of "" around text *myDiv*? My controller method is that produces this HTML:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getSerialRanking", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public String getSerialRankings(@RequestParam(value = "serialNumber", required = false) String serial){
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In html single word properties without quotes are legal so

`<div class=myDiv>`

is converted by your browser to this

`<div class="myDiv">`

Based on that knowledge I'm assuming your Spring Controller is auto converting the value to `<div class="&quot;myDiv&quot;">` Then your browser converts the `&quot;` to a legal HTML entity `"`.

> The `&quot;` is ignored until it reaches the browser where it is converted to a legal HTML entity `"`

Finally I think your safe to remove the `&quot;` for this case. Or if your using more than one words in your HTML property go with @ElliottFrisch solutions:

```
append(sb ,"<div class=\"myDiv\">");
append(sb ,"<div class='myDiv'>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use HTML quotes, I think you want to change

```
append(sb ,"<div class=&quot;myDiv&quot;>");
```

to escape the double quotes like

```
append(sb ,"<div class=\"myDiv\">");
```

**or** HTML allows you to mix quotes, so you could say

```
append(sb ,"<div class='myDiv'>");
```